# How do i upload an attachment on a form Developed using lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a lightning component basically a form, i need to add to it the functionality of attachments so when i save the the form after the details have been entered a record saved in the specific object should contain the attachment uploaded onto the form but the criteria for the file to be attached is that the functionality should be able to upload files of size 10mb or above, max 50mb so how can I achieve this

Comment: Are you trying to create a new component? If not, what's the specific issue that you're having? If yes, again, what have you done and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach, but the maximum will be **4.5 MB**: 
https://gist.github.com/peterknolle/bb4b7ac63f67f66c32b0

Don't think you can go up to 20MB.

Check this post about people that has tried this before: 
http://peterknolle.com/file-upload-lightning-component/

Answer (score 0):

You can using the rest api. You will have to enables cors access for your domain and also get a valid session Id. To get the session Id, I created a simple VF page and parsed it using getpagecontent and using DOM.xml reader.